# Screen Flow error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY when the Id is not null and correct

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, screen-flow

I have a screen flow to attach a file to a Account record and update few fields on the Account as shown below:
[image]

The flow gives the below error when executing :
"The flow tried to update these records: null. This error occurred: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: invalid cross reference id."

Step 1: I can attach a file in my first screen component and it gets uploaded to the correct Account as well.

Step 2: [Update File Name]: The attached file has to be renamed - is not working. Debug logs show that it's failing for the next steps to be executed.

[image]

Step 3: [Update records - client Safety Risk register]: fails with the below error message
[image]

I checked the highlighted record Id and it points to the right Account Id.

I am not sure which Id is cross referenced here. I checked the content document ID and other Ids in the debug as well. All are valid Ids and I can see their relevant records as well.

Would appreciate help in resolving this issue!

Many thanks

Comment: Can you please confirm,if you have access to all the fields which are being referenced in the flow as this error occurs if we do not have the enough level of access on the fields or Object which are being invoked.

Comment: Yup, I have access to the fields and the object. It works in DEV but just not in UAT.

Comment: Did you try with any other user like system admin? If so can you check access for the user profile the one who is getting this error. If access is there then please check if that user has access to this specific record or not. Most probably it sharing or permission issue because same logic is running in lower env.

Comment: Hi, this is only happening in partial copy sandbox. I checked all access and everything is correct